# What is the purpose of creating an object in XML?

Tags: javascript, xml, magento

```
var ajxobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajxobj.open('GET','sample.xml',false);
ajxobj.send();
var myobj = ajxobj.responseXML;
```

What is the purpose of this code in XML?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: What has [tag:magento] to do with your question?

Comment: Ya got it...thank u